# Chrome console opens in new window on page load

Tags: google-chrome

I am working on a website in my Wordpress installation. However, for some reason, when i reload one specific page (local server, otherwise I would post the link here for you to check) I experience the following problem:

- Page is open, with Google Chrome console is open on the right
- On reload, the console opens a new blank console window, with following url displayed at the top: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?isSharedWorker=true&remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@94xxx(some number)/&dockSide=undocked

This only happens on one specific page, is there a way this can be produced involuntarily by some code? (I haven't written any javascript or so that explicitely would do this function). Is there any way this behavior is known? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I have this same problem. Did you solve it?